# Express | How to connect local server with an app that has its own token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, token

UPDATED QUESTION:

We have an application running React on the UI, and a variety of languages, and APIs coming from the backend.

Currently, the team cannot develop an API, fast enough for us to test against it, and develop it.

We used Dyson, a JSON Web Server, to mock some Data, but it is not ideal. Our application is using a bearrer Token, which we get by hitting the `api/auth` endpoint on our server.

We have mocked it, in the Dyson Server, exactly, and every time, we want to hit our mock server, we change the endpoint from `api/auth` to `http://localhost:PORT/api/auth`, and we just copy /past the TOKEN from the normal path to our mock server in order for the app to load.

But that has a lot of limitations. I am planning to have the same behavior on our new express server that we built. But how are we doing that with express. Take that Token, and use it witht that specific api/endpoint.

Hope I was more clear in that explanation.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Are you asking how to serve HTTPS with Express? Are you asking how to read/write auth headers in Express and/or React?

Comment: I have updated the question, as best as I can explain it. Hope it helps you understand it a little bit better. Thanks!!